# Looking for help identifying bathroom faucet

Tags: faucet

I'm looking for help identifying this faucet from the 2000s or 2010s. It's in a Restoration Hardware bathroom vanity, but I don't think that's the faucet brand here.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a generic brand found on internet shopping sites.  Is there a problem?

Comment: It's leaking from the hot water side, so I was hoping to identify so I know the cartridge I need to replace it. Thanks.

Comment: disassemble it and take the cartridge to the pluming store

Comment: Look for a label on the hot or cold water supply pipe under the vanity

Answer (score 2):

Google Lens image search results:

[Pfister Carnegie
2-Handle Roman Tub Trim Kit](https://ca.pfisterfaucets.com/bathroom/product/carnegie-rt6-5we-2-handle-roman-tub-trim-kit)

[image]